# Passport Github strategy not working and throwing errors

Tags: node.js, passport.js, passport-github2

The code below is getting mad at me. I don't see anything wrong with it.

```js
function User(profile){
   console.log(profile)
}

passport.use(
    new GitHubStrategy({
            clientID: "my_id",
            clientSecret: "secret",
            callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/github/callback",
        },
        function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
             User(profile),function (err, user) {
                 return done(err, user);
             };
        }
    )
);
app.get(
    "/auth/github",
    passport.authenticate("github", { scope: ["user:email"] })
);

app.get(
    "/auth/github/callback",
    passport.authenticate("github", { failureRedirect: "/login" }),
    function(req, res) {
        // Successful authentication, redirect home.
        res.redirect("/");
    }
);
```

It's throwing a big error every time I try to authenticate. Please help.

Edited the question and did as @jasonandmonte said and now I get this:[image: The I now get after following instructions from an answer.]

Comment: I haven't worked with either of these libs but usually, with OAuth, you need to exchange the auth code that retuned on the callback to an access token and refresh token. Have you done this anywhere?

Comment: well i know that this part is throwing error function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
             User(profile),function (err, user) {
                 return done(err, user);
             };

Comment: just don't know why

Comment: One thing I noticed on the documentation that it uses `User.findOrCreate()` instead of `User()`

Comment: when i was using ```User.findOrCreate ```it was saying User is not defined i don't know why it's saying that

Comment: so I did some modifications but it's still throwing hell lot of errors.

Comment: Can you try to replicate their "working example" here? https://github.com/cfsghost/passport-github/blob/master/examples/login/app.js

Comment: What's wrong with my code? Need help ASAP! That error is killing me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue I am seeing is you are defining a `User` function that is only logging the profile. The `User` function in the documentation is an example of a database model that queries a database and passes data to a callback.

To resolve the issue and replicate how `passport-github`'s example does it, you will need to use an object modeling tool like Mongoose or Sequelize. You will then have access to something similar to `User.findOrCreate()` or just `User.find()` if you want to restrict account creation to an admin role.

To get passport working until you setup a database connection though, you should be able to update the strategy callback to invoke done.

```js
passport.use(
    new GitHubStrategy({
            clientID: "my_id",
            clientSecret: "secret",
            callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/github/callback",
        },
        function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
             done(null, profile.id);
        }
    )
);
```

Comment: thanks @jasonandmonte. did as you said and now i get a new error.

Comment: What does your express app file look like? You need to use `passport.initialize()` middleware in your express app. If that sounds unfamiliar I would recommend reviewing a passport oauth 2.0 tutorial or [example code](https://github.com/passport/express-4.x-facebook-example/blob/master/server.js) to look at a more comprehensive setup for passport.